# Slightly changing print output in x iterations

Tags: python

I've got this code:

```py
for l in range(1,11):
    print("{0:<{1}}{2}".format(str(l), 1, ". ") + "{0:<{1}}".format("Hello", 10) + "{0: <{1}}".format("hey", 5) + "  |  something")
```

Which outputs this:

```
1. Hello     hey    |  something
2. Hello     hey    |  something
3. Hello     hey    |  something
4. Hello     hey    |  something
5. Hello     hey    |  something
6. Hello     hey    |  something
7. Hello     hey    |  something
8. Hello     hey    |  something
9. Hello     hey    |  something
10. Hello     hey    |  something
```

Now my main problem is in the last line, is there a way to keep same distance?

So it would be like this?

```
1. Hello     hey    |  something
2. Hello     hey    |  something
3. Hello     hey    |  something
4. Hello     hey    |  something
5. Hello     hey    |  something
6. Hello     hey    |  something
7. Hello     hey    |  something
8. Hello     hey    |  something
9. Hello     hey    |  something
10. Hello    hey    |  something
```

I have found out, that I could do this basically this way:

```py
for l in range(1,11):
   if len(str(l)) == 1:
        print("{0:<{1}}{2}".format(str(l), 1, ". ") + "{0:<{1}}".format("Hello", 10) + "{0: <{1}}".format("hey", 5) + "  |  something")
   elif len(str(l)) == 2:
        print("{0:<{1}}{2}".format(str(l), 1, ". ") + "{0:<{1}}".format("Hello", 9) + "{0: <{1}}".format("hey", 5) + "  |  something")
```

```
1. Hello     hey    |  something
2. Hello     hey    |  something
3. Hello     hey    |  something
4. Hello     hey    |  something
5. Hello     hey    |  something
6. Hello     hey    |  something
7. Hello     hey    |  something
8. Hello     hey    |  something
9. Hello     hey    |  something
10. Hello    hey    |  something
```

**Which works well, but is there a more elegant way of doing this, without making multimple ifs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation on venkatadileep's answer that uses format strings by adding an f-string for the varying part of the line.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print('{:<13}{:<7}|{:>11}'.format(f'{i}. Hello',
                                      'hey','something'))
```

We just require that the first part of each line up to `hey` is aligned left and has a width of 13.

The output would be as requested:

```
1. Hello     hey    |  something
2. Hello     hey    |  something
3. Hello     hey    |  something
4. Hello     hey    |  something
5. Hello     hey    |  something
6. Hello     hey    |  something
7. Hello     hey    |  something
8. Hello     hey    |  something
9. Hello     hey    |  something
10. Hello    hey    |  something
```

Answer (score 2):

What about tabs?

```
In [3]: for l in range(1, 11):
   ...:     print(f'{l}.\tHello\they\t|\tsomething')
   ...:     
1.  Hello   hey |   something
2.  Hello   hey |   something
3.  Hello   hey |   something
4.  Hello   hey |   something
5.  Hello   hey |   something
6.  Hello   hey |   something
7.  Hello   hey |   something
8.  Hello   hey |   something
9.  Hello   hey |   something
10. Hello   hey |   something
```

They might fail to work if the lengths of things are quite uneven, though, or when terminal settings are not as you expect.

Comment: With tabs the output depends on the terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
for l in range(1, 11):   
   print("{0:<{1}}{2}".format(str(l).zfill(2), 1, ". ") + "{0:<{1}}".format("Hello", 10) + "{0: <{1}}".format("hey", 5) + "  |  something")
```